# How to use vector to modify a struct c++

Tags: c++, vector, struct

Hey guys this code is for a coffee machine. I am trying to add a operator mode for this machine.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct coffee {
  string name;
  int itemprice;
  string country;
  int quantity;

};

float remainder, price2, price;
int main() {
      int coffeetype = 1; 
    cout<<"\nPress'1'for buy a coffee\n";
    cout<<"\nPress' 2' for operator mode\n\n";
    int input;
    cin>>input;
    if (input==2)
    {
        cout << "Welcome to operator mode \n";
        cout << "Press '1' for add more coffee powder \n";
        cout << "Press '2' for exit\n";
        int op;
        cin >> op;
        if(op==2){
            return op;
        }
    }
        coffee drink[] = {
      { "Espresso", 120, "Italy", 20 },
      { "Iced coffee", 150, "France", 20 },
      { "Long black", 80, "Austral", 20 },
      { "Americano", 100, "America", 20 },
      { "Latte", 200, "Italy", 20 },
      { "Irishcoffee",130, "Ireland", 20 },
      { "Cappuccino", 180, "Italy", 20 }
    };

        cout << fixed;
        cout << setprecision(2);

   cout<<"Enter the name of coffee";



    while(coffeetype != 8){
    for (int i = 0; i != sizeof(drink)/sizeof(drink[0]); ++i)
        cout<< "\n " << i+1 << ") "<<drink[i].name<<"\t\t"<<drink[i].itemprice<<"\t\t"<<drink[i].country<<"\t\t("<<drink[i].quantity<<") remaining";
```

I've used a vector for this struct part.

```
vector<coffee> drink {
    { "Espresso", 120, "Italy", 20 },
    { "Iced coffee", 150, "France", 20 },
    { "Long black", 80, "Austral", 20 },
    { "Americano", 100, "America", 20 },
    { "Latte", 200, "Italy", 20 },
    { "Irishcoffee",130, "Ireland", 20 },
    { "Cappuccino", 180, "Italy", 20 }
};
```

but after using this part my 'for loop' didn't work..
Could some one help me to 'cout' the vector part.

And also i need your help to make the operator mode.By operator mode operator should be able to add more coffee types and change the number of coffees in the machine..Below i have shown the code i got from one of the contributor in stackoverflow.But i dont know how to implement below code part to my code.

```
coffee entry;
cin >> entry.country
    >> entry.itemprice
    >> entry.country
    >> entry.quantity;
drink.push_back(entry);
```

How to use above code to modify details in the struct(drink).

Comment: Some of the code in the bottom of the first block code is missing.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, did you use `for (int i = 0; i != sizeof(drink)/sizeof(drink[0]); ++i)` with `drink` being a vector?

Comment: Yes i used it.Is it wrong?So how to use it with a vector.Could you explain me?

Comment: You Sir, have a very neat coding style

Answer (score 3):

First, `drink` is a poor choice of name for the array, which holds information regarding many dirnks - and in fact, many coffee-based drinks. So let's call it `coffee_drinks`.

The problem with your for loop is *probably* your use of:

```
sizeof(drink)/sizeof(drink[0])
```

this "hack" works for C-style arrays - not for `std::vector`s. The `sizeof()` an `std::vector` is *not* the total size in bytes of its elements - since the memory of the elements is dynamically allocated on the heap, and is only *pointed to* by the vector class instance.

You could just write:

```
for(int i = 0; i < coffee_drinks.size(); i++)
```

but even better, you can make it:

```
for(coffee drink : coffee_drinks)
```

which iterates over all elements in the `std::vector`. This "trick" works for any class which has a `begin()` and `end()` member; it's called a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: Could you correct it?Cuz i'm not good with vectors.Actually i learned it yesterday?

Comment: Mm i just changed the code.BTW it runs without errors..But it does not show any data inside the struct.It just shows the '0' mark for every space where coffee names should appear.I think some think wrong with my                                                                  "cout<< "\n " << i+1 << ") "<<drink[i].name<<"\t\t"<<drink[i].itemprice<<"\t\t"<<drink[i].country<<"\t\t("<<drink[i].quantity<<") remaining";"                                                         part.Could you tell me whats wrong with it?